# How to apply Date filter to SamePeriodLastYear in Power BI DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, business-intelligence

I want to calculate the **Active Customer** number change between two years, so
I created a DAX measure to calculate the customer count for this year and other for last year:

**Active Customer** : I want to explain what that means:

There are two columns in the customer table :  FirstRegistrationDate and RegistrationExpiryDate

the active customer for a specific date must have a date in FirstRegistrationDate before the select date.

and RegistrationExpiryDate is biger than the select date.

Example :

For date: 01/31/2021

FirstRegistrationDate < 01/31/2021.

RegistrationExpiryDate > 01/31/2021.

**The Measuers:**

CustomerCount :

```
DISTINCTCOUNT(VWCRs[id])
```

CustomerCountLastYear :

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(VWCRs[id]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(VWCRs[FirstRegistrationDate].[Date]),         
SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(VWCRs[RegistrationExpiryDate].[Date]))
```

Then

```
Customer YOY = CustomerCount - CustomerCountLastYear

Customer YOY% = (CustomerCount - CustomerCountLastYear) / CustomerCountLastYear
```

without applying date filters: the results of CustomerCount and CustomerCountLastYear are different and seem logical.

**The Problem** is when I use a two filter to specify the FirstRegistrationDate and other for RegistrationExpiryDate I got the same result for both CustomerCount and CustomerCountLastYear and Customer YOY% = 0.0%.

I use the Auto-Date of power bi.

[image]

Comment: Not easy to give an answer. Seems it should work. Generaly, try to avoid slicer based on the data table, use calendar table instead. In your case I'd use 2 calendar tables and link them to FirstRegistrationDate and to RegistrationExpiryDate accordingly. The function SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR gives you all visible dates in the data table and then offset them for a year. The problem can come if, for example, the slicer shows 1/31/2021 but the last date in FirstRegistrationDate is - 1/15/2021 so you will get offset for a 1/15/2021 not for 1/31/2021.

Comment: So, if you have gaps in dates you will have a problem.

Comment: I will try to apply what you suggest, but I don't think the problem is with the slicer, it is the mesure, the date filter is not applied on the SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR as it should be. How to force the filter in the mesures ?

Comment: in your measure SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(VWCRs[FirstRegistrationDate]) change to SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR([RelativeCalendarTableName])

Comment: Please, let me know if it will work.

Comment: Hi agian, If you solved the problem already, would be interesting to see the solution.

Comment: hi Mik, sorry but I didn't solve it yet and because of the work load I jumped to anther task , I will update you here if I manage to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in Auto-Date. Your slicers comes from table date fields and Auto-Date, in the measure - VWCRs[...].[Date], simply ignores your slicers (no idea why). In fact, your data is limited only by one year from the latest date in the table and this is the reason why you get the value Customer YOY% = 0.0%. So, to make it works you can change the measure as below or make 2 calendars as I advice you in comments. If you will use calendars slicers should made of them and use calendars in SamePeriodLastYear expressions. Both variants are checked and works.

```
VAR RegDates = 
    DATESBETWEEN(
        VWCRs[FirstRegistrationDate]
        ,MIN(VWCRs[FirstRegistrationDate])
        ,MAX(VWCRs[FirstRegistrationDate])
    )
VAR ExpDates=
    DATESBETWEEN(
        VWCRs[RegistrationExpiryDate]
        ,MIN(VWCRs[RegistrationExpiryDate])
        ,MAX(VWCRs[RegistrationExpiryDate])
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(VWCRs[id])
        ,SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(RegDates)
        ,SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(ExpDates)
    )
```